# sequence of tenses in a compound sentences

Tags: complex-sentences

> I used to play hockey, but now I play football.
>
> He ate my cake yesterday, so I will eat his cake today.

As these are compound sentences and in both of these sentences the first clause is in past tense and the second clause is in present/future tense. Is it all right to use them so? As we know, when we have complex  (not compound but complex) sentences, the past is generally followed by a past.

Comment: Yes, they are fine. A small point, though: both your examples are complex, not compound, sentences. The first has the dependent clause "to play hockey" as complement to "used" and in the second, the _so_ preposition phrase has the dependent _will_ clause as complement.

Comment: @BillJ Isn't *so* a coordinating conjunction here?

Comment: *As we know,....* How do we know this?

Comment: Probably the same way _we_ know that there is a sequence of tense rule in English. I.e, somebody once told _us_, and _we_ always believe anything that somebody tells _us_ -- or at least _we_ do if it's about grammar.